# How to remove object which does not match?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for basic question. But, I really need your help. I want to filter data from this variables(filter by array object with the object). I really need your help I already spend much time with this simple logic.

I have data as below:

```
const option1 = { "Dashboard": true, "Gift": true, "User": true};

const option2 = [
  {
    path: '/admin/dashboard',
    title: 'adminPanel.dashboard.title',
    key: 'Dashboard'
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/user',
    title: 'adminPanel.userManagement.title',
    key: 'User'
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/credit',
    title: 'adminPanel.creditManagement.title',
    key: 'Credit'
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/gift',
    title: 'adminPanel.giftManagement.title',
    key: 'Gift'
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/staff',
    title: 'adminPanel.staffManagement.title',
    key: 'Staff'
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/audit',
    title: 'adminPanel.auditManagement.title',
    key: 'Audit'
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/config',
    title: 'adminPanel.configManagement.title',
    key: 'Config'
  }
]
[
  {
    path: '/admin/dashboard',
    title: 'adminPanel.dashboard.title',
    key: 'Dashboard',
    active: false,
    subOptions: null
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/user',
    title: 'adminPanel.userManagement.title',
    key: 'User',
    active: false,
    subOptions: null
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/credit',
    title: 'adminPanel.creditManagement.title',
    key: 'Credit',
    active: false,
    subOptions: null
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/gift',
    title: 'adminPanel.giftManagement.title',
    key: 'Gift',
    active: false,
    subOptions: null
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/staff',
    title: 'adminPanel.staffManagement.title',
    key: 'Staff',
    active: true,
    subOptions: null
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/audit',
    title: 'adminPanel.auditManagement.title',
    key: 'Audit',
    active: false,
    subOptions: null
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/config',
    title: 'adminPanel.configManagement.title',
    key: 'Config',
    active: false,
    subOptions: null
  }
];
```

I want to filter between **option1 & option2(with key)**. If **key in option2** not match in **option1** the object will be remove.

The result should be:

```
result = [
  {
    path: '/admin/dashboard',
    title: 'adminPanel.dashboard.title',
    key: 'Dashboard'
  },
{
    path: '/admin/gift',
    title: 'adminPanel.giftManagement.title',
    key: 'Gift'
  },
{
    path: '/admin/user',
    title: 'adminPanel.userManagement.title',
    key: 'User'
  },
]
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Also, `option2` is not a valid object, there are 2 lists combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `object.keys` like this:

```js
const option1 = {
  "Dashboard": true,
  "Gift": true,
  "User": true
};

const option2 = [{
    path: '/admin/dashboard',
    title: 'adminPanel.dashboard.title',
    key: 'Dashboard'
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/user',
    title: 'adminPanel.userManagement.title',
    key: 'User'
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/credit',
    title: 'adminPanel.creditManagement.title',
    key: 'Credit'
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/gift',
    title: 'adminPanel.giftManagement.title',
    key: 'Gift'
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/staff',
    title: 'adminPanel.staffManagement.title',
    key: 'Staff'
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/audit',
    title: 'adminPanel.auditManagement.title',
    key: 'Audit'
  },
  {
    path: '/admin/config',
    title: 'adminPanel.configManagement.title',
    key: 'Config'
  }
]

var f = option2.filter(t => Object.keys(option1).includes(t.key));
console.log(f);
```